# Do i need to add anything else in config file?

Tags: spring-rabbit

This is my config class.

```
@Configuration
public class MessageConfig {

public static final String KEY = "anil_key";
public static final String EXCHANGE = "anil_exchange_one";
public static final String QUEUE = "anil_queue";

@Bean
public Queue queue() {

    return new Queue(QUEUE, false);
}

@Bean
public DirectExchange exchange() {
    return new DirectExchange(EXCHANGE);
}

@Bean
public Binding binding(Queue queue, DirectExchange exchange) {

    return BindingBuilder.bind(queue).to(exchange).with(KEY);

}

@Bean
public MessageConverter converter() {
    return new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter();
}

@Bean
public AmqpTemplate template(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
    final RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate = new RabbitTemplate(connectionFactory);
    rabbitTemplate.setMessageConverter(converter());
    return rabbitTemplate;
}
```

and this is my publisher class

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/order")
public class Publisher {
@Autowired
private AmqpTemplate rabbitTemplate;

@PostMapping("/{restaurentName}")
public String bookOrder(@RequestBody Order order,@PathVariable String restaurentName) {
    
order.setOrderId(UUID.randomUUID().toString());

OrderStatus status = new OrderStatus(order,"progress","successfully received");

rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(MessageConfig.EXCHANGE, MessageConfig.KEY, status);

return "success";
    
}
```

I am getting below error.

2020-10-04 14:28:24.628 ERROR 17008 --- [ 127.0.0.1:5672] o.s.a.r.c.CachingConnectionFactory       : Channel shutdown: channel error; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=404, reply-text=NOT_FOUND - no exchange 'anil_exchange_one' in vhost '/', class-id=60, method-id=40).

Answer (score 1):

You need a `RabbitAdmin` `@Bean` to declare the exhange/queue/binding.

```java
@Bean
RabbitAdmin admmin(ConnectionFactory cf) {
    return new Rabbitadmin(cf);
}
```

Comment: How to add RabbitAdmin?

Comment: After adding RabbitAdmin also facing same issue.

Comment: Turn on DEBUG logging to see the admin activity when the connection is opened.

Comment: Channel shutdown: channel error; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=404, reply-text=NOT_FOUND - no exchange 'anil_exchange_one' in vhost '/', class-id=60, method-id=40)

Comment: Then there is something amiss; post your complete project someplace so I can see what's wrong.